# How to handle formatting like bold, italic, images, etc with resource bundle internationalization

Tags: jsf, internationalization

I am using JSF 2.0 framework to build a web application.
I know how to handle java web application internalization (i18n) using `ResourceBundle`.
This approach is suitable when you have to work on single words or phrase.

But when you have an entire paragraph or a whole text whith formatting (blod, italic, images, etc), how can we handle i18n in this case? Because of formatting, I don't know if it will be a good idea to put that text in a properties file.

Comment: The question was asked multiple time here. Just search for answers. In short, yes please **always** include formatting elements in properties, otherwise translators won't stand the chance to remove them or change for something more appropriate (this also depends on culture).

Comment: @PawełDyda I got this question as result while searching on google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not really a standard for this. It's in general affordable as long as you don't put markup which represent layout in the resource bundle files. Elements representing layout are usually HTML [block](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html) elements like `<div>`, `<p>`, `<h1>`, etc. So, you need to make sure that you restrict to using HTML [inline](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html) elements like `<b>`, `<i>`, `<img>`, `<span>`, `<br>`, etc in properties files.

Comment: ok! thanks for your responses. so now how to handle i18n for text containing elements representing layout , HTML block elements like <div>, <p>, <h1>, etc.... Shall I avoid using properties file and putting them directly in view(html page)

Comment: Just don't put them in properties file. Put them in the view instead. E.g. `<h1>#{i18n['viewid.header']}</h1><p>#{i18n['viewid.paragraph']}</p>` and so on.

Comment: ok thanks BalusC , I got the point. I thought a simple solution was existing.